# Sorting dhcpd.conf

Tags: awk

We have a shared *dhcpd* server where we set fixed IPs for our sandbox servers. Due to limitations of the subnetwork we can't avoid we are forced to have a limited and small range of static IP addresses to assign.

Due to this and other coworkers adding/removing hosts from the `dhcpd.conf` file, it is quite long and messy right now and it should be sorted out.

Since all ip declarations follow this pattern:

```
host foo {
  hardware ethernet 00:00:00:00:00:00;
  fixed-address 192.168.192.X;
}
```

Could this be done with `awk`? If so, how? I have never tried something this complex with it.

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but are you sure the static IPs are the right answer to the root problem? Most cases when people want some machines in a DHCP environment to have static IPs could be solved by `mdns`, addressing the server as `sandbox42.local` instead of some fixed IP.

Comment: Sadly, we can't use mdns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this can be done with `awk`:

```
BEGIN { RS = "}"; }
{
    match($0, /fixed-address ([^;]+);/, array);
    data[array[1]] = $0;
}
END {
    n = asorti(data, dest);
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        print data[dest[i]] RS;
    }
}
```

Comment: My knowledge of `awk` is pretty basic, this is a program file to be passed to `awk`, right?
I have tried `awk -f foo dhcpd.conf` (being foo a file with your code) but the output is in the same order than the original file. How should I use this?

Comment: You are using it correctly. Are you sure your sample input is adequate?

Comment: I had some comments in the file, once they've been removed it is working as expected. Thank you.